# delete element out of array with $pull and $cond operators

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to pull elements out of the array only if some condition is met

This is my document structure:

```
{
   _id: "userId",
   posts: [{
      _id: "postId",
      comments:[{
         _id: "commentId",
         userid: "some id of an user" // USER
      },{
         _id: "commentId2",
         userid: "some id of an user2"
      }]
   }]
}
```

I want to delete the element from the `comments` array with the given **commentId**. This should be done only if `userid` is `USER`. If that condition isn't met, that means that comment doesn't belongs to the user that wants to delete it so I decline it.

**Tried Attempt :**

```
 Post.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
      },
      {
        $pull: {
          $cond: [
            {
              "posts.$[post].comments.$[comment].userid": {
                $eq: USER
              }
            },
            {
              $pull: {
                comments: {
                  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(commentId)
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            "comment._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(commentId)
          },
          {
            "post._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId)
          }
        ]
      }
    )
```

That code above doesn't work, I'm stuck there & I don't know how to continue. maybe somebody knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) // Fetches actual document
      },
      // Any matching object that has these fields/values in comments array will be pulled out
      {
        $pull: {"posts.$[post].comments": { _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(commentId), "userid": USER }}},
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          {
            "post._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId) // Checks which object inside `posts` array needs to be updated
          }
        ]
      }
    )
```

**Note :** Use an option `{ new : true }` in mongoose to return updated document, or in shell use `{ returnNewDocument : true }`

Comment: i copy / paste it and it almost worked. just edited 1 thing `USER` needs to be converted to object id `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(USER)`

Comment: another question about performance: the query will search every comment that has the id `USER`. Is it possible to add additional condition like `count: 1`? I know there is only 1 comment but mongodb will search every comment with that USER and this is unneccesary.

Comment: @Ifaruki : No there is no way to specify count, It's ok it will be good enough cause you've already filtered on `_id` & also have an additional filter on `post._id`, So only thing it needs to iterate on is `comments` array for one post object, I guess that's ok as we can't do anything much..